# Set up environment variables IIS Windows server for vue.js

Tags: vue.js, iis, environment-variables

I want to setup environment variables in IIS to use in my vue.js v2.6.12 app I've used the following method, but looks like that their value isn't accessible in app (is undefined)

#### My ultimate goal is to make a hot-swappable option to be able to change base API address without rebuilding.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

         <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".gltf" mimeType="gltf/gltf" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="VUE_APP_BASE_API" value="https://example.com/api/v1" />
    <add key="VUE_APP_BASE_YARDVIEW" value="https://example.com" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You should create a `.env` file. For more details, you can check the official doc: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

Comment: @JasonPan `.env` file is for local testing and is never served to the server, I want to set env variables on the IIS webserver, my use case is that I want to easily change env variables without having to rebuild.

Comment: Hi Rocky, I don't agree with you. Seems the .env not works in your server, you should check the MIME type in IIS.